# rails 5 API; update single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone let me know how I can update a single record in a table using rails 5 API.

For eg; I need to update the quantity field that has a row ID of 5. I would like to pass the values in the URL as follows:

```
localhost/items_list/5/qty/1
```

My update controller is like:

```
@order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
@order_item.update_attribute(:qty,params[:qty])
```

How should the route look for this?

Comment: try post 'items_list/:id/qty/:qty', to: 'your_controller#your_action' or resources :items_list; member do;  post 'qty/:qty'; end; end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define the routes in order this expects to receive the values you'll send as params, maybe something like:

```
put 'item_list/:id/qty/:qty', to: 'item_list#edit' # depending on the controller's name and action
```

This is defining your route to expect the item_list `id` and the `quantity` to use as value for updating the record.

Then in your controller you can use `find` to get the specific element which to update, and then passing the `params[:id]` to update the attribute with the value of `params[:qty]`:

```
@order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id]).update(qty: params[:qty])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Had to change it from get to PUT. Appreciate your help.